# Why the table cell default selection style is not returned? Swift 5.2

Tags: tableview, cell, swift5

Why the default style for the selectionStyle property in the tableview cell is not returned? I wrote a condition to check and the print command works, i.e. it shows that default style is returning. But the table cell is not grayed out, as it should be with the default style.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)

    if cell?.selectionStyle == .default {
        cell?.selectionStyle = .none
        print("none")

    } else  {
        cell?.selectionStyle = .default
        print("default")
    }        

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to the problem. The fact is that the return of the style works, it just is not visible, because the change is very fast.

To see how the cell selection style changes (white color changes to gray and vice versa) you just need to click on the cell and hold it pressed for a while. And then you can see how the cell is grayed out.